# Why should we wrap await inside an async function?

Tags: javascript

Why should we have an async function in order to use await? Why can't we just use await without async? JS is async by default too, this just adds to the confusion.

Update:
I've seen some lads put my question on hold so I'll try to elaborate.
I'm just curious as to why this won't work:

```
some code
let users = await getUsers();
some code
```

Why should it be inside an async for it to work, ie

```
$(async function() {
    some code
    let users = await getUsers();
    some code
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "JS is async by default"?

Comment: Do you mean that `await` should work on the top level of a script, or do you mean that `await` should work within a normal `function`?

Comment: Regarding your edit, what does the `$(…)` wrapper around the `async function` do?

Answer (score 1):

> JS is async by default too...

No, JavaScript is not async by default. The only async features of JavaScript are fairly newly-added:

- Promise resolution
- `async`/`await`

JavaScript is commonly used in environments where you interact with asynchronous things (like event handlers in the DOM, or I/O completions in Node.js), but JavaScript is not asynchronous (other than above).

In [the words of](https://twitter.com/awbjs/status/1139649437385363456) Allen Wirfs-Brock, who was the editor of the ECMAScript specification for many years, JavaScript...

> (has) an observably synchronous execution model. Other than via Atomics/SABs there are no observable shared-state race conditions.

Back to your question:

> Why should we have an async function in order to use await?

Before too long, with modules you won't have to, once the [top level `await` proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) finishes working through the [process](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/). It just got to Stage 3.

But the answer is that `await` is syntactic sugar for consuming a promise, and one of the rules of promises is that you either handle errors or return the chain to the caller (so it can handle errors or return the chain to *its* caller). `await` doesn't handle errors, so it has to return the chain to the caller. The way it does that is that an `async` function always returns a promise, and that promise is chained to the promise `await` awaits.

That is, this:

```
async function foo() {
    const thingy = await somethingAsyncReturningAPromise();
    return thingy.foo;
}
```

is *conceptually* (but not literally) this:

```
function foo() {
    return somethingAsyncReturningAPromise()
        .then(thingy => thingy.foo);
}
```

If something goes wrong in `somethingAsyncReturningAPromise`, the promise returned by `foo` rejects — the error is propagated to the caller.

As far as I can tell from the top-level `await` proposal, it simply allows unhandled rejections at the top level of the module to be unhandled rejections. So just like this code causes an unhandled error:

```
null.doSomething();
```

this code in an async module would cause an unhandled rejection:

```
await somethingThatReturnsAPromiseAndRejects();
```

Comment: JavaScript is strongly based on task based concurrency, so "JS is not async by default" is a terse statement

Comment: @JonasWilms - You're confusing the language and the environments in which it's popular. :-)

Comment: No, I'm not. Job queues are specified. Every engine that does not implement task based concurrency is not spec compliant.

Comment: Oh and callbacks are not "asynchronous" ?

Comment: @JonasWilms - No, callbacks are not asynchronous.

Comment: If we say "Promises are just wrappers around callbacks" then promises aren't async too?

Comment: @JonasWilms - Promises aren't just wrappers around callbacks. What makes Promises inherently async is that the spec says that a `then`/`catch`/`finally` handler will be called asynchronously, even if the promise is already settled.

Comment: Right, promise resolution always ends up in a job queue. But job queues are not specific to promises, and they exist longer than promises. If thats your reason to call "Promises are async", then they derive their asynchrony from the job concept. Then, everything that ends up on the job queue is asynchronous.

Comment: @JonasWilms - No, not at all. Promises are async because they're defined async. Queuing a job is just *how* promise settlement callbacks are made async.

Comment: then I'd like to see a quote of the spec that defines that "Promises are async". According to that logic `setTimeout(function b() { })` is not async too.

Comment: @JonasWilms - `setTimeout`'s definition says it's async too. Compare with `Array#sort`, which is not.

Answer (score 0):

> Why should we have an async function in order to use await? Why can't we just use await without async?

Because `async`/`await` is "just" *syntactic sugar* for Promises. If the function is async, then it returns a Promise. It is not possible to have the "await" behaviour without returning a promise. The fact that the function is async has to be marked explicitly.

> JS is async by default too, this just adds to the confusion.

This statement is too "simplified". While it is true that JS is async in nature, because of the event loop, this doesn't mean that every function has an async behavior. This does not add to the confusion. You're probably confused due to misunderstanding how JS really works. You should read about Promises, which are behind the scenes when you see `async`/`await`.

Comment: *"While it is true that JS is async in nature, because of the event loop"* The event loop doesn't make JavaScript async in nature. In fact, JavaScript *isn't* async in nature, other than the recently-added promise resolution asynchronousness and `async` functions (and soon, `async` modules aka top-level `await`).

Comment: @t.j. I disagree. Without asynchronous events, the event loop would be senseless. Yes, the ES spec does not define such event sources (as it leaves that to other specs), but in fact JS is event based.

Comment: @JonasWilms JS is not event-based, although it is used in an event-based environment (node.js, DOM) most of the time. There are JS engines with threads for concurrency as well, they're just pretty unpopular.

Comment: @bergi is that even spec compliant? I mean Realms cannot share execution contexts?

Comment: @JonasWilms No idea :-) [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Runtime#Contexts_and_Threads) was developed long before the EcmaScript spec cared about this - you're right that all recent development (promises, workers, realms, shared memory, atomics etc) is based on independent threads running event loops and using message passing for communication.

Comment: @JonasWilms - Different realms can't share execution contexts (that's part of the definition of a realm), but different threads can share the same realm. They don't on browsers or Node.js, but they *can*. It's not prohibited as far as I recall. (I've been pretty deep into the spec the last couple of years, but that doesn't mean I didn't miss something.)

Comment: @bergi yup, so JS is *de facto* and *de jure* event based

Comment: @t.j.crowder sure but two threads can't execute the same realm at the same time, right? I think I've read that somewhere.

Comment: @t.j.crowder whoops, I was mixing up terms. The spec calls threads "agents", and it states "Execution of a Job can be initiated only when there is no running execution context and the execution context stack is
empty." and "Each agent has its own set of named Job Queues". I think that basically prohibits concurrency.

Comment: @JonasWilms - "Agents" aren't threads. But I need to go into that section of the spec, it's not outside the realm (no pun!) of possibility that TC39 decided fairly recently (~ES2015) to disallow true multi-threading. I don't think they did, but it's not impossible that they did.

Comment: @t.j.crowder then what are threads? Agents can run concurrently and have seperate memory. Thats what I'd call a thread.

Comment: @JonasWilms - A thread doesn't have to have its own memory, just its own stack. But my basic disagreement here is that event based means async by nature. I don't think that's true. Heck, Win16 (remember that? you're probably too young) was event based, but not remotely async. Famously, a single app could stall the entire event loop. (I'm off for dinner/evening, and SO comments probably probably isn't the right place fo this. Just FYI, I've asked Allen Wirfs-Brock about the true multithreading thing [which is also unrelated to "async nature"]. I'm not sure I don't read it the same way you do.)

Comment: @t.j.crowder yup, I'm too young for that, but I think I get your point there. A single thread is not multithreading, and a single job can't be asynchronous. But the job queue only makes sense if you have multiple jobs, thus the spec implies that JS has task based concurrency. For sure there might be environments with just one job,

Comment: @JonasWilms - AWB confirms that the spec (now) defines that an agent "provides a a single threaded, run-to-completion execution environment." and JavaScript "(has) an observably synchronous execution model. Other than via Atomics/SABs there are no observable shared-state race conditions."

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has task based concurrency. It basically means that code blocks (tasks) runs synchronously without being interrupted, until it reaches a certain breakpoint (the end of a task). That has some advantages:

1) You do have concurrency, e.g. a network call does not block your script from doing other things in the meantime (so the task that consumes the network request will only run if the network request was done, other tasks can be done in the meantime).

2) On the other hand, you do not have concurrent mutations, which eliminates a lot of problems (`let a = 1; a += 1;` could evaluate to 3, you would need locks / semaphores to prevent those, c.f. Java & others).

Now `async` / `await` allow you to define such tasks:

An async function can be divided into tasks, `await` serves as a breakpoint:

```
  let a = 1;
  async function stuff() {
    a = a + 1; // this is totally secure, as no other code might run in the meantime
    a = a + await other(); // this is unsafe, as we await, which means that other tasks might be executed in the meantime.
  }
```

If you want to "await in non async functions" that basically means that you won't know wether a certain function call runs synchronously (meaning: without other code running in  the meantime) or not:

```
  function dangerous() { await stuff(); }

  let a = 1;
  a = a + dangerous(); // does that work or not? Can a be manipulated in the meantime?
```

So with your proposal you would basically remove the borders around tasks, every code might run every inbetween. So at the end that causes chaos, and chaos is not good if you want to be productive.

Comment: That a network call does not block has nothing to do with JavaScript. It only has to do with the environment JavaScript is being used in. JavaScript is just a language. Technically you could plug in any language into the browser can get the same results. Similarly you could plug JavaScript into any other project. Plug it into DOOM instead of Lua. The language itself has nothing to say about those things except that unlike C/C++ and other languages the spec is explicit that no JavaScript state can be shared. State outside the scope of JavaScript is just that, outside the scope of JavaScript.

Comment: @gman sure, but the spec defines jobs & job queues to enable task based concurrency. Yes, without an environment that creates async jobs that job queue is useless, but it is hard to give examples just from the spec.